# finding render path for file in eclipse workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, portlet

I am trying to get a view.jsp file to display another .jsp file as a popup however I keep getting resource not found errors.  Both files reside in the same directory in an Eclipse workspace.  I was told that I need to use the files render path.  I'm not sure how to find/create a render path for a file.  The code activating the popup looks like this:

```
<a href="popupex.jsp" onclick="return popitup('RenderPathGoesHere.jsp')">
     <input type="submit" value="Single Issue Upload" name="SingleIssueUpload"><br>
</a>
```

I'm kinda new to portlet development so any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create portlet render url to redirect to jsp
i.e

```
<portlet:renderURL var="varName">
    <portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/html/foldername/RenderPathGoesHere.jsp" />
</portlet:renderURL>
```

And you can call like this

```
<a href="${varName}">Click</a>
```

HTH

Comment: where do I put the function call to popitup()?